# Type 'UIColor?' has no member 'myColor'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, colors, uicolor

I am using NVActivityIndicatorView to load custom animation, and wanted to change the color of the animation, I used my color extention to load my own custom color, but it gives me an error of type uicolor has no member of myColor !

```
extension UIColor {
    static let myCustomColor = UIColor(red: 47, green: 85, blue: 173)
}
    

    let myColor = UIColor.myCustomColor
    
    private let loading = NVActivityIndicatorView(frame: .zero, type: .lineScale, color: .myColor, padding: 0)
```

Comment: `color: .myColor`, your are trying to call `UIColor.myColor`, not `let myColor = UIColor.myCustomColor`. Did you meant `color: myColor` instead?

Comment: @Larme I want to call this extension UIColor.myCustomColor, but it is not showing the color !

Comment: In your loading var remove color: .myColor --> Remove .(dot)

Comment: @Larme yes U used this color: UIColor.myCustomColor but it is not loading the color, it does not load anything actually because it is not reading the color

Comment: Is UIColor(red: , green: , blue: ) an extension? If it is I think there is an error in it.
Can you please try this one `static let myCustomColor = UIColor(red: 0.18, green: 0.33, blue: 0.68, alpha: 1.00)`

Comment: @excE it worked!! thank you so much the issue was my extension color int

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.myCustomColor` or `myColor`, without dot.

```
private let loading = NVActivityIndicatorView(frame: .zero, type: .lineScale, color: myColor, padding: 0)
```